# C# SSLStream read, Stream read tcpclient

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I am writing an application that needs to communicate over SSL/TLS.

When I use the following code, the device connects, but I always read 0 bytes:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;

        do
        {
            // Read the client's test message.
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            sslStream.Flush();

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8 
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
```

When I use this code, I am able to read bytes but obviously not decode them. This code reads the correct number of bytes, what is going wrong with the SSl that I would not get any bytes back?

```
            var client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

            // Get a stream object for reading and writing
            var stream = client.GetStream();

            // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client. 
            while (stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length) != 0)
            {
                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine(base64);
```

Bigger sample, I think this is from MSDN:

```
    static void ProcessClient(TcpClient client)
    {
        // A client has connected. Create the  
        // SslStream using the client's network stream.
        SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
        // Authenticate the server but don't require the client to authenticate. 
        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate,
                false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
            // Display the properties and settings for the authenticated stream.
            DisplaySecurityLevel(sslStream);
            DisplaySecurityServices(sslStream);
            DisplayCertificateInformation(sslStream);
            DisplayStreamProperties(sslStream);

            // Set timeouts for the read and write to 5 seconds.
            sslStream.ReadTimeout = 5000;
            sslStream.WriteTimeout = 5000;
            // Read a message from the client.   
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client message...");
            string messageData = ReadMessage(sslStream);
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", messageData);

            // Write a message to the client. 
            byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello from the server.<EOF>");
            Console.WriteLine("Sending hello message.");
            sslStream.Write(message);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inner exception: {0}", e.InnerException.Message);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            // The client stream will be closed with the sslStream 
            // because we specified this behavior when creating 
            // the sslStream.
            sslStream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }

    static string ReadMessage(SslStream sslStream)
    {
        // Read the  message sent by the client. 
        // The client signals the end of the message using the 
        // "<EOF>" marker.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
        StringBuilder messageData = new StringBuilder();
        int bytes = -1;

        do
        {
            // Read the client's test message.
            bytes = sslStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            sslStream.Flush();

            // Use Decoder class to convert from bytes to UTF8 
            // in case a character spans two buffers.
            Decoder decoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
            char[] chars = new char[decoder.GetCharCount(buffer, 0, bytes)];
            decoder.GetChars(buffer, 0, bytes, chars, 0);
            messageData.Append(chars);
            // Check for EOF or an empty message. 
            if (messageData.ToString().IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        } while (bytes != 0);

        return messageData.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Obviously there is something going on with the stream provided by the *sslStream* variable. Since your question doesn't show how you did setup *sslStream*, this is all i can say ;)

Comment: I added more code, this is just 1 of many examples I have found online, they all do the same thing.

Comment: Well, it's always a bad idea to copy'n'paste examples and then hoping that all will just magically work fine. Remember, code examples given in documentations such as MSDN are not meant to be complete, robust code. They are meant to **illustrate** or explain something to help you understand how to use a particular class/method/etc... I would suggest trying to understand the code given in the examples and do some debugging with regard to finding out what really happens. Do you just guess that the code reads 0 bytes, or how did you confirm that this is really the case? (contd...)

Comment: Perhaps the code is not reading from the stream at all, but bails out before due to some exception/error...

Comment: I was wondering if the code is not using the stream, I do not seem to be able to catch any exceptions. I know the code is returning 0 bytes or timing out, because I have run this in the debugger and looked at the variables. I also have wireshark running and can see there is 307bytes in the data stream, this is the exact number of bytes I get back when I use the NetworkStream. I am just trying to get some ideas of why I cannot get anything from the SSLStream.

Comment: Set breakpoints (1) at the beginning of the *catch* block, (2) at the beginning of the *finally* block, and (3) at the last line of the *try* block. If the debugger hits the breakpoint in the *finally* block but not hitting the breakpoint on the last line of the *try* block, you know that something has failed. Better yet, enhance your code so that it not only catches AuthenticationException's, but catches any exception (will make it much easier trouble-shooting any kind of issues...)

Comment: Voting to close because you can't seem to decide on a single code example and focus on a specific problem. Nobody can answer your question if you don't provide at least enough information to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Let me add this, I am trying to communicate with an SSL enabled device. I tried connecting to the server with Chrome and it did get data on the stream. I also noticed that in the stream properties it has a value for the client certificate and it is always null. Do I need to load the client certificate? I understand that in some situation the client certificate is sent and verified, however in this situation I have both the public and private keys used.

Answer (score 0):

I did end up solving this eventually and wanted to post the answer for everyone. The certificate was self-signed, thus "invalid", but this is common on devices. I had to create a validation callback that always returned true.

I forget where I found this code but I think it was MSDN

```
    // The following method is invoked by the RemoteCertificateValidationDelegate.
    private static bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        //DisplayCertificateInformation((SslStream)sender);

        if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            return true;

        Debug.WriteLine("Certificate error: {0}", sslPolicyErrors);

        // Allow this client to communicate with unauthenticated servers.
        return true;
    }
```

I ended up extending the TcpClient Class:

```
public class TlsTcpClient : TcpClient
{
    public TlsTcpClient()
    {

    }

    public TlsTcpClient(string ip, int port) : base(ip, port)
    {

    }

    public new SslStream GetStream()
    {
        var sslStream = new SslStream(base.GetStream(),
            true,
            ValidateServerCertificate,
            null);

        try
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("Certname goes here");
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Exception: {e.Message}");
            if (e.InnerException != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Inner exception: {e.InnerException.Message}");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("Authentication failed - closing the connection.");
            return null;
        }

        return sslStream;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Find below a example of a Client-Server communicating through sslstream [original source  here](https://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/165902-sslstream-client-certificates.html)

Server

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _certificate = "certificate-string";
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 13000);

        server.Start();

        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

        SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, VerifyClientCertificate, null);

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(_certificate));

        stream.AuthenticateAsServer(certificate, false, 
            SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13, false);

        if (stream.RemoteCertificate != null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(stream.RemoteCertificate.Subject);
        }
        else
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("No client certificate.");
        }

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        bool clientClose = false;
        while (!System.Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data...");
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", line);
             
            if (line == "close")
            {
                clientClose = true;
                break;
            }

            writer.WriteLine(line);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        if (!clientClose) System.Console.ReadKey();

        stream.Close();
        server.Stop();
    }

    private static bool VerifyClientCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Client

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var _certificate = "certificate-string";
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13000);

        SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, VerifyServerCertificate, null);

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(_certificate));

        stream.AuthenticateAsClient("127.0.0.1", new X509Certificate2Collection(certificate), 
            SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13, false);

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);

        while (true)
        {
            string line = System.Console.ReadLine();
            writer.WriteLine(line);
            writer.Flush();
            if (line == "close") break;
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            System.Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", line);
        }

        stream.Close();
        client.Close();
    }

    private static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```